# How to match a class somewhere below an id, and only there?

Tags: css

In the code below, I want to apply a blue background only to the element with the text "blue" (which is a child of the element `#hello`), but not any other elements that have that class (here: "not blue!").

`#hello>*.setcolor` is my (failed) attempt to say *"for the element with id `hello`, apply the style to any child element that has the class `setcolor`*.

```css
#hello>*.setcolor {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="hello">
  <div>
    <div class="setcolor">
      blue
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="setcolor">
  not blue!
</div>
```

Comment: Much of your description including for example `.q-field__control` is not in the sample code provided.  That being said this can be a super simple set of CSS however your "constraints" you attempted to describe are not clear.

Comment: Yes, I wanted first to point to the actual component I am using, and then provide simple code to reproduce the issue. But you are right, I will remove the first part that does not add much value. I will attempt to clarify the constraints - and yes, i am sure it is super simple :)

Comment: This shoud work: *any* `class` inside `id` is `#id .class { .. }` (with a space) and *only direct child* elements would be `#id>.class { .. }` (with an angle bracket).

Comment: you could also use a data attribute and set CSS based on the value `.setcolor[data-color="orange"] {
      background-color: #ffa50080;
    }` for this: `<div class="setcolor" data-color="orange">`

Comment: The question has been closed incorrectly, OP is asking for a `#hello .setcolor` rule specifying that the element has to have a child text node with the content blue. That question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text . This would be possible with javascript though

Comment: @Blye The question was closed correctly. OP's problem is using `>` while not understanding that it only applies to direct (immediate) descendants. Removing the `>` changes the selector to a general descendant/child selector, which will work per OP's specifications. This is what the duplicate target is about (the differences between direct descendant and general child selectors)

Comment: My bad, the `I want to apply a blue background only to the element with the text "blue"` was ambiguous wording